# How to target last child of a list with SASS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

My HTML is structured like this -

```
    <ul id="primary-menu">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a>Item 1</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li class="menu-item">
              <a>Dropdown Item 1</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a>Item 2</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li class="menu-item">
              <a>Dropdown Item 2</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I am trying to target the last item in the dropdown menu, "Dropdown Item 2"

This is my SASS -

```
    #primary-menu {
      .dropdown-menu {
         &:last-child {
          .dropdown-item {
            width: 424px;
          }
       }
     }
    }
```

But my width style shows up on both items. In dev tools it looks like this -

```
    #primary-menu .dropdown-menu:last-child .dropdown-item {
    width: 424px;
    }
```

How can I target only the second drop down item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular html

```
#primary-menu > .menu-item:last-child .menu-item:last-child { ... }
```

If written in SASS, it would be something like

```
#primary-menu {
  > .menu-item:last-child .menu-item:last-child { 
    ...
  }
}
```

This is assuming you have more items in the dropdown menu.

your css did not work because you had multiple dropdown-menu and they are both last child of their parent container, so it would target all of them.

You needed to target the last menu-item that is the child of primary-menu then target the menu-item last child.

```css
#primary-menu > .menu-item:last-child .menu-item:last-child {
  background: green;
  width: 424px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="primary-menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a>Item 1</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a>Dropdown Item 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a>Item 2</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a>Dropdown Item 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation